# When to use もちろん, うん, and はい?

Tags: words

In my understanding :

- もちろん = of course
- はい = yes
- うん = yes

When is each of them more appropriate to use, or is it basically just preference? Are other options more *casual* than the other options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

もちろん is used when you want to say "of course". If you need it to be formal => もちろんです。

はい is formal to say yes and other stuff.

うん is like はい but casual, not to use to people you *protocolly* respect.

Comment: It is worth to add ええ as well, which is better to be positioned between はい and うん by the politeness. Here's a good material about the usage of these words: http://www.nier.go.jp/saka/pdf/N13012049.pdf